# "-" character in Asterisk diaplan

Tags: regex, asterisk

I'm running Asterisk 11.4.0. I need to make an external line, which uses for EVERY outgoing call. So, I'm don't know what dial rule I have to write in my extensions.conf. It's not a problem to write a line, which matches every numeric string:

```
_X.
```

I also know how to make it match every string, which consists of numbers and letters:

```
_[0-9a-zA-Z].
```

But you can also meet some special symbols in sip accounts, and I speak about symbol "-" (for example my account's name is "just-me@godlike-provider.com). How can I make a mask for strings like that?

Comment: you can use  \-   in your regex

Comment: You mean   _[0-9a-zA-Z\-].   will work?

Comment: for example: if you want to match just-me@godlike-provider.com, you can use [0-9a-zA-Z\-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+\.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" \ -" works fine. Thank you, Tim.Tang.